# SQL Server - returning xml child nodes for xml column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

Given table T with columns:

```
ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
CreatedDate DATETIME
XmlData XML
```

Where XmlData is structured like:

```
<application>
    <details firstname="first" lastname="last">
        <statement>statement</statement>
    </details>
    <educationHistory>
        <education subject="subject1" />
        <education subject="subject2" />
    </educationHistory>
    <experienceHistory>
        <examiningExperienceHistory>
            <examiningExperience module="module1" />
            <examiningExperience module="module2" />
        </examiningExperienceHistory>
        <teachingExperienceHistory>
            <teachingExperience module="module1" />
            <teachingExperience module="module2" />
        </teachingExperienceHistory>
    </experienceHistory>
</application>
```

I need to return an extract like so:

```
ID Date       FirstName LastName Education    ExaminingExp TeachingExp
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  02-10-2012 First     Last     <xmlextract> <xmlextract> <xmlextract>
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT ID,
       CreatedDate [Date],
       XmlData.value('(application/details/@firstname)[1]','varchar(max)') [FirstName],
       XmlData.value('(application/details/@lastname)[1]','varchar(max)') [LastName]
FROM T
```

I'm struggling with thee last three columns. For each record, I need to list teaching/examining experience, and education. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `.query` to extract xml.

eg

```
select 
XmlData.query('/application/educationHistory/*'),
XmlData.query('/application/experienceHistory/examiningExperienceHistory/*'),
XmlData.query('/application/experienceHistory/teachingExperienceHistory/*')
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Just to be cheeky, is there a way I can restrict what is returned in the query? e.g. instead of return the full xml under the path, return only certain attributes. So given `<education subject="subject1" grade="grade" />`, return only `<education subject="subject1" />`,

Comment: You can do `xmldata.query ('data(/application/educationHistory/education/@subject)')` which will get the value of the subject attribute

Comment: @podiluska Not with query(), but with value().

Comment: You can filter the nodes you want to be returned. I.e. `@xmlVar.query('/application/educationHistory/education[@subject="subject1"]')`, but you cannot filter the returned attributes. Every attribute in the returned nodes will be returned

Comment: @podiluska True, sorry, I misunderstood your comment. This returns the values of that attributes in all the nodes under that XQuery path.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, Created [DATE] 
XmlData.value('(application/details/@firstname)[1]','varchar(max)') [FirstName],
XmlData.value('(application/details/@lastname)[1]','varchar(max)') [LastName],
XmlData.query('/application/educationHistory'),
XmlData.query('/application/experienceHistory/examiningExperienceHistory'),
XmlData.query('/application/experienceHistory/teachingExperienceHistory')
FROM T
```