# How to extract the xml child node using sql

Tags: c#, sql, xml, model-view-controller, nodes

I am having column of datatype xml in my database.

sample value shown below.

```
<Responses>
   <Response>
     <task></task>
   </Response>
  <Response>
     <task></task>
   </Response>
  <Response>
     <task></task>
   </Response>
</Responses>
```

So from the above xml I need to extract each   node and need to save it as different row in another table. From the above example there will be 3 rows.

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: I can take values of each node using select command from xml, but i am not able to extract the node itself. In c# i have done it. we will get the child nodes

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: through an api I will get an xml response and i am inserting it to a db table as xml, in that xml response itself there will be several responses as child nodes, Once after inserting this xml to table later using a stored procedure i need to read the saved xml and extract each responses in it and insert it into another table. in the above example  assume it as the response of api which i am inserting first. Then i need to read this xml data and extract each child node in that xml to different tables as xml. <Response> <task></task>
   </Response> 3 of this child  node i need to extract

Answer (score 1):

try using the xml column, query.  you will need to cast a string column to xml then use query. see ([SQL Server - returning xml child nodes for xml column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690689/sql-server-returning-xml-child-nodes-for-xml-column))

```
declare @tmp as table (ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
CreatedDate DATETIME,
XmlData XML)

declare @xml as xml='<Responses>
   <Response>
     <task>1</task>
   </Response>
  <Response>
     <task>2</task>
   </Response>
  <Response>
     <task>3</task>
   </Response>
</Responses>'

insert into @tmp(CreatedDate,XmlData) values(GetDate(),@xml)


select XmlData.query('Responses/Response/task') task from @tmp
```

output:

```
<task>1</task><task>2</task><task>3</task>
```

using xml path nodes and value

```
select X.Y.value('(task)[1]','int') task from @tmp t
cross apply t.XmlData.nodes('Responses/Response') as X(Y)
```

output

```
 task
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: Slight difference: yours takes each `Response` and pulls out the first `task`, mine goes straight to `task`. Theoretically if there are multiple `task` nodes you would get only the first from each `Response`, although there's no indication from OP that this is the case

Comment: are you saying <task><task>1</task></task> ?  why would I have such a structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following SQL XQuery solution:

`.query` will give you a whole XML node, rather than `.value` which only gives you a single inner value.

```sql
SELECT x.task.query('.') task
FROM @tmp t
CROSS APPLY t.XmlData.nodes('Responses/Response/task') x(task);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1f371b6dc74d4948440ce7d0b421498)

**Output:**

| task |
| --- |
| `<task>1</task>` |
| `<task>2</task>` |
| `<task>3</task>` |

Comment: @GoldenLion It "applies" the result of the `.nodes` Table Valued function to each row, and that function will "explode out" the nodes (the ones which matche the XQuery input) into separate rows. See the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15. The `.query` function will return an XML result, in this case we ask for `.` which is the whole node

Comment: thanks I used it to unpivot my xml results

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = @"<Responses>
                               <Response>
                                 <task></task>
                               </Response>
                              <Response>
                                 <task></task>
                               </Response>
                              <Response>
                                 <task></task>
                               </Response>
                            </Responses>";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(reader);
        }
    }
}
```